# Getting NSURLSESSION data from OpenWeatherMap Api crashing app

Tags: ios, iphone, openweathermap

I'm getting `openweathermap` weather data from `NSURLSession`.
In the United Kingdom, the app launches perfectly well and loads as expected, but when I load the app outside of the UK, the app crashes because of this weather API. 
Even when using the Xcode simulator which has the simulated location of the US, the application crashes.
I can't work out why? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
-(void)getWeather{
NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sharedSession];
        NSString *urlString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=%@,%@&APPID=(APIKEYREMOVED)", city, country];
    NSURL *weatherURL = [NSURL URLWithString:urlString];
    [[session dataTaskWithURL:weatherURL
                completionHandler:^(NSData *data,
                                    NSURLResponse *response,
                                    NSError *error) {
                    [weatherIcon removeFromSuperview];
                    [temperature removeFromSuperview];
                    NSMutableDictionary *allData = [ NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers error:&error];
                    __block  NSString* currentWeather = nil;
                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), ^{
                        weatherIcon = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(14, 12, 28, 30)];
                        [weatherIcon setContentMode:UIViewContentModeScaleAspectFit];
                        [_scrollView addSubview:weatherIcon];
                        temperature = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(42, 11, 32, 34)];
                        temperature.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%@",[allData[@"main"][@"temp"] floatValue] - 273.15, @"\u00B0"];
                        [temperature setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0f%@",[allData[@"main"][@"temp"] floatValue] - 273.15, @"\u00B0"]];
                        [temperature setTextAlignment:NSTextAlignmentCenter];
                        [temperature setFont:[UIFont fontWithName:@"Helvetica-Light" size:21]];
                        temperature.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
                        [_scrollView addSubview:temperature];

                        [self setWeatherIcon];

                    });
                    NSArray* weather = allData[@"weather"];
                    for (NSDictionary* weatherDictionary in weather)
                    {
                        static dispatch_once_t once;
                        dispatch_once(&once, ^ {
                            currentWeather = weatherDictionary[@"main"];
                            weatherType = currentWeather;
                        });

                    }

                }] resume];
}
```

Error:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'data parameter is nil'
*** First throw call stack:
(
    0   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112a58b0b __exceptionPreprocess + 171
    1   libobjc.A.dylib                     0x0000000112154141 objc_exception_throw + 48
    2   CoreFoundation                      0x0000000112ac1625 +[NSException raise:format:] + 197
    3   Foundation                          0x000000010f311df3 +[NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:options:error:] + 67
    4   Car Mode                            0x000000010e036964 __37-[ViewController getLocalWeatherData]_block_invoke + 228
    5   CFNetwork                           0x0000000116f4787b __75-[__NSURLSessionLocal taskForClass:request:uploadFile:bodyData:completion:]_block_invoke + 19
    6   CFNetwork                           0x0000000116f47095 __49-[__NSCFLocalSessionTask _task_onqueue_didFinish]_block_invoke + 143
    7   Foundation                          0x000000010f2e5237 __NSBLOCKOPERATION_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_A_BLOCK__ + 7
    8   Foundation                          0x000000010f2e4f3b -[NSBlockOperation main] + 101
    9   Foundation                          0x000000010f2e36f7 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 627
    10  Foundation                          0x000000010f2df47c __NSOQSchedule_f + 198
    11  libdispatch.dylib                   0x000000011641605c _dispatch_client_callout + 8
    12  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001163f494f _dispatch_queue_serial_drain + 221
    13  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001163f5669 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 1084
    14  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001163f7ec4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 634
    15  libdispatch.dylib                   0x00000001163f7bef _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 123
    16  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001167a8616 _pthread_wqthread + 1299
    17  libsystem_pthread.dylib             0x00000001167a80f1 start_wqthread + 13
)
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type NSException
(lldb)
```

I understand that the data is returning nil, but why is it returning nil only outside of the UK?

After adding the `NSLog` as suggested:

```
Error Domain=NSURLErrorDomain Code=-1002 "unsupported URL" UserInfo={NSLocalizedDescription=unsupported URL, NSUnderlyingError=0x61000025f5f0 {Error Domain=kCFErrorDomainCFNetwork Code=-1002 "(null)"}}
```

Comment: The reason is API URL is incorrect. Please check out your API URL.

Comment: The API URL is correct, the API works perfectly well in the United Kingdom, I receive the correct weather data. @Anbu.Karthik, when i copy paste the URL into the browser, it returns the correct data also.

Comment: check once bro , you missed the any value

Comment: Anbu is most liekly correct, before *allData, add NSLog(@"%@\n", error)

Comment: Okay anbu and @SeanLintern88, thanks you two, I have added the NSLog, please check the original post to see the new error it has output.

Comment: ok assign the URL instead of inlining it, i.e. set it a variable, and print that also

Comment: edited original post. Still crashing with same error :S @SeanLintern88

Comment: yeah can you NSLOG the URL, so removing your API key, it sounds like it could be URL encoding is the issue

Comment: @SeanLintern88 yes, I'm currently testing with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters`, it seems to be changing the http:// to `http%3A%2F%2Fapi`

Comment: @SeanLintern88 perfect!! if you submit answer ill accept it, thanks!

Comment: done :D, glad to help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode your URL with `stringByAddingPercentEncodingWithAllowedCharacters` with `URLQueryAllowedCharacterSet`